# How to remove focus on a Rails button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dom-events

I have the following button defined in my rails app:

```
<%= button_to "Delete Account", user_path(@user), method: :delete,data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'button' %>
```

When the delete button is clicked on the confirm dialog box that pops up, the "Delete Account" button remains in focus which I would like to take out of focus because of the pulsating text due to the CSS styling. Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.button,input[type=submit]
{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: #ccc;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #666, 0 5px 0 #444, 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
  transition: all 150ms ease;
}     

.button:hover,.button:focus,input[type=submit]:hover,input[type=submit]:focus
{
  -webkit-animation: pulsate 1.2s linear infinite;
  animation: pulsate 1.2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate
{
  0%   { color: #ddd; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000; }
  50%  { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #444, 0 0 5px #ffd, 0 0 8px #fff; }
  100% { color: #ddd; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000; }
}

@keyframes pulsate
{
  0%   { color: #ddd; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000; }
  50%  { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #444, 0 0 5px #ffd, 0 0 8px #fff; }
  100% { color: #ddd; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000; }
}

.button:active,input[type=submit]:active
{
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #444, 0 0 5px #ffd, 0 0 8px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #666, 0 2px 0 #444, 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
  transform: translateY(3px);
  -webkit-animation: none;
  animation: none;
}
```

I am getting my Javascript from the following source:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

I believe there is a Javascript solution but it is beyond me. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Take a look the this thread, it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7954205/1505348

Comment: Thanks, it did help. I am learning javascript as I work my way through rails.

Answer (score 1):

I added an id to the button:

```
<%= button_to "Delete Account", user_path(@user), method: :delete, data:  {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'button',id: 'del-button' %>
```

and added this script:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("del-button").onclick = loseFocus;
function loseFocus() 
{
    document.getElementById("del-button").blur();
}
</script>
```